# running docker-compose returned -1 on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, docker-compose

When running the following docker compose file

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - "./app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - "db"

db:
  image: mongo
```

in windows 7 i receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "docker-compose", line 3, in
>      File "compose\cli\main.py", line 88, in main   File
>   "compose\cli\main.py", line 140, in perform_command   File
>   "compose\cli\main.py", line 900, in up   File "compose\project.py",
>   line 385, in up   File "compose\project.py", line 590, in
>   warn_for_swarm_mode   File "site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line
>   73, in info   File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line
>   47, in inner   File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 179, in
>   _get   File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get   File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request   File
>   "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send   File
>   "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send   File
>   "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 595,
>   in  urlopen   File
>   "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 363,
>   in  _make_request   File "httplib.py", line 1042, in request   File
>   "httplib.py", line 1082, in _send_request   File "httplib.py", line
>   1038, in endheaders   File "httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
>   File "httplib.py", line 844, in send   File
>   "site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 31, in connect
>   File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 22, in
>   wrapped   File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line
>   50, in connect pywintypes.error: (2, 'WaitNamedPipe',
>   '\xfe\xfe\xec\xee\xf2\xf8\xeb\xfa \xe0\xe 9\xef
>   \xe0\xf4\xf9\xf8\xe5\xfa \xec\xe0\xfa\xf8 \xe0\xfa
>   \xe4\xf7\xe5\xe1\xf5 \x f9\xf6\xe5\xe9\xef.') Failed to execute script
>   docker-compose

Did someone encountered this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution for me → run cmd with admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error under Windows 10 using Powershell and the command line. Even after installing Python and adding it to the path.

I tried running docker-compose using the Docker Quickstart Terminal, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

solution for me → run with Docker Quickstart Terminal on windows 7

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in a bit more details.